# Take the difference based on ID

Tags: r

I have a df with 212 rows in the form of:

```
ID visit treatment value1 value2 value3
1    V0      A        2.6     3.4   .1
1    V1      A        2.3     4.6   .5
2    V0      B        1.3     5.4   .6
3    V0      A        1.6     5.4   .7
2    V1      B        1.8     4.5   .3
3    V1      A        1.3     7.3   1.2
```

So o have a column with ID, one with visit week and treatment and a bunch of columns with values. I want to take the difference for each ID, the treatment is the same for each ID, it never change from week 0 and 1. The ID don't necessarily comes in order. Is this possible?

It would be something like:

```
ID visit treatment value1 value2 value3
 1  v0-v1    A       0.3   -1.2     -.4
```

and so on.

Comment: Are there only two visits (0 and 1)? How about treatment? Possible values per ID are A-A and A-B?

Comment: Are there cases where you only have one visit? or more than 2 visits?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a data.table solution:

```
dt[by=.(ID,treatment),j={
    z <- nrow(.SD);
    c(
        .(visit=paste0(visit[1L],'-',visit[z])),
        lapply(mget(grep(value=T,'^value',names(.SD))),function(x) x[1L]-x[z])
    );
}];
##    ID treatment visit value1 value2 value3
## 1:  1         A V0-V1    0.3   -1.2   -0.4
## 2:  2         B V0-V1   -0.5    0.9    0.3
## 3:  3         A V0-V1    0.3   -1.9   -0.5
```

**Data**

```
library(data.table);
dt <- data.table(ID=c(1L,1L,2L,3L,2L,3L),visit=c('V0','V1','V0','V0','V1','V1'),treatment=c(
'A','A','B','A','B','A'),value1=c(2.6,2.3,1.3,1.6,1.8,1.3),value2=c(3.4,4.6,5.4,5.4,4.5,7.3),
value3=c(0.1,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.3,1.2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your data in the form of a csv with , delimiter just to test the code.
Assuming i have the data in a dataframe called inpstack

```
inpstack<-read.csv("/XXX/input.csv",header=TRUE)
library("sqldf")
stack1<-sqldf("select * from inpstack where visit='V0'");
stack2<-sqldf("select * from inpstack where visit='V1'");
stack3<-sqldf("select a.ID, 'V0-V1' as visit,(a.value1-b.value1) as value1,(a.value2-b.value2) as value2,(a.value3-b.value3) as value3 from stack1 a join stack2 b on a.ID=b.ID")
```

The stack3 df has the below output

```
ID,visit,value1,value2,value3
1,V0-V1,0.3,-1.2,-0.4
2,V0-V1,-0.5,0.9,0.3
3,V0-V1,0.3,-1.9,-0.5
```

Hope this helps. I have used sqldf library

This will only work for the above scenario where there will be only 2 visits V0 and V1

Comment: Definetly it will be a tedious task to work with 300 values we may need some other approach for it

Comment: In the question it is specified that it has 212 rows with defined table structure. So, I considered it will be of the same, used the above code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% group_by(ID,treatment) %>% summarise_each(funs(diff,toString(visit)),value1,value2,value3)
result[1:6]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are exactly two visits per ID-treatment, you could use `aggregate` as follows:

```
aggregate(cbind(value1, value2, value3)~ID + treatment, data=df, function(i) i[1L]-i[2L])
  ID treatment value1 value2 value3
1  1         A    0.3   -1.2   -0.4
2  3         A    0.3   -1.9   -0.5
3  2         B   -0.5    0.9    0.3
```

If the set is not balanced, you could insert an `if` statement that would return NA or some other value:

```
aggregate(cbind(value1, value2, value3)~ID + treatment,
          data=df, function(i) {if(length(i) == 2L) i[1L]-i[2L] else NA})
```